# Can't connect to a class Atlas cluster from the MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb

How can I connect to a class Atlas cluster from the MongoDB shell?

While connecting to the MongoDB Atlas cluster I may see the following warning message:

> ... WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time in stack overflow but thank you..